# Python - Aren't packages relative to their current directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay, I've got a file structure like the following:

- main.py/
- paquete/

  - __ init__.py
  - test1.py

This is what I've got in my main.py:

```
from paquete import testFunc


def main():
    testFunc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what I've got in my test1.py:

```
def testFunc():
    print("Hello from test1 function!")
```

And this is what I've got in my __ init__.py:

```
from test1 import testFunc
```

But that doesn't work, it says that there's no module named test1.

However, if I have something like:

```
from paquete.test1 import testFunc
```

It works perfect. But I don't get it, if __ init__.py it's in the same directory as test1, why do I need to prefix it with the name of the directory as if I was working from the root level of the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently using is called an **implicit relative import.**  It was deprecated in Python 3.x and this is mentioned in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

You can still use a relative import; it just needs to use the [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) described below, with leading dots:

> These imports use leading dots to indicate the current and parent packages involved in the relative import.

```
# Relative
from .test1 import testFunc

# Absolute
from paquete.test1 import testFunc
```

Also a [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) -

> The only acceptable syntax for relative imports is `from .[module] import name`. All import forms not starting with `.` are interpreted as absolute imports. (PEP 0328).

Comment: I wish I could mark two responses as accepted. Haha Thank you for your response, everything makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `paquete` is in your `sys.path` but the insides of the package are not. So you can make absolute imports for `paquete` package but can only make relative imports for its insides. `paquete` is on you `sys.path` because it is in the same directory are you main.py.

You can set the `__path__` attribute before the imports to get the insides of the package to be considered by the import statement.

Take a look at this for reference https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#module-path

Comment: Uhm that makes more sense now. Thank you for your response. :)